# Lightning Community - Top of Page Cut Off

Tags: lightning, community, error

I have a Lightning Community using the Partner template. Sometimes when I go to a page, the top inch or so doesn't load. The space isn't empty - it's totally gone and the rest of the content has shifted up to take it's place. This is happening on various types of pages, so it's not an issue with a specific component, e.g. Home page, Record Detail page. I also opened the dev console and didn't see any errors. The issue seems unpredictable and intermittent. If I refresh the page, the page usually loads correctly.

**Example of page that loaded successfully**
[image: Successful Page Load]

**Example of cut off - welcome message is missing**
[image: Cut Off]

Comment: Did you report this to salesforce?

Comment: @gNerb Yes, still waiting to hear back.